# string indices must be integers while parsing JSON - python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, integer, indices

I am new to python and facing this error: `string indices must be integers` while parsing a JSON file.

JSON File:

```
{"NFLTeams": [
  {"code":"ARI","fullName":"Arizona Cardinals","shortName":"Arizona"},
  {"code":"ATL","fullName":"Atlanta Falcons","shortName":"Atlanta"},
  {"code":"WAS","fullName":"Washington Redskins","shortName":"Washington"}
]}
```

My code:

```
import urllib.request as ur
import urllib.parse
import json

url = 'http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/nfl-teams/json/test/'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read().decode('utf-8')

print (the_page)
team_data = json.loads(the_page)

print (type(team_data))  // team_data is type dict

for item in team_data:
    print (item['NFLTeams'][0]["code"])
    print (item['NFLTeams'][0]['fullName'])
    print (item['NFLTeams'][0]['shortName'])
```

I have tried to print the following:

```
print (item['NFLTeams']["code"])
```

And this:

```
for item in team_data['NFLTeams'].values():
    print (item["code"])
    print (item['fullName'])
    print (item['shortName'])
```

Which gives me this error:

```
for item in team_data['NFLTeams'].values():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what's going on? Thank you.

Comment: `team_data['NFLTeams']` is a `list`, not a `dict`, and therefore does not have a `values` method. You should `print` the entire `team_data` object to see what it actually is, and then you can work out how to access it.

Comment: When asking `python` question on Stack Overflow, please specify which version of python you are using, and tag your question either `python-2` or `python-3`. It may not be relevant to this question, but it generally helps.

Comment: thank you for bringing that up. I will keep it in mind while posting questions    next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.values()` is used to loop through the values of a dictionary however, `team_data['NFLTeams']` is a `list` containing dictionaries. Thus, you need to remove `.values()` to access each dictionary whilst iterating:

```
for item in team_data['NFLTeams']:
    print (item["code"])
    print (item['fullName'])
    print (item['shortName'])
```

If you really want to use `.values()`:

```
for item in team_data.values()[0]:
    print (item["code"])
    print (item['fullName'])
    print (item['shortName'])
```

Please keep in mind that `.values()` returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) in Python 3.x, so you need to force evaluating it using `list()` in order to access the elements by index:

```
for item in list(team_data.values())[0]:
```

Comment: You can't do `[0]` with a `values` view.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I assumed he is using Python 2.x despite the usage of `print`

Comment: Oh, one of the old eager functions, got it.